# Concatenated String Echos Out of Order in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, echo, string-concatenation

I have a problem with this short script that has been killing me for the past day.

I am trying to concatenate a value from a mysql database table into a string and the output is out of order.

Consider the following code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT something FROM table");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $foo ='<iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/' . $row[0] . '%';
    echo $foo;
}
```

The output of this results in:

`%iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/84a42780062ce000dcb5`

My desired output is this:

`<iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/84a42780062ce000dcb5%`

Why is it that anything concatenated after the $row[0] gets pushed to the front of the string? And why is the "<" getting ignored entirely in the output?

How can i achieve my desired output?

**From comments**:

I should add that i'm doing this in **the command line** from my server.

Comment: I don't think it's getting pushed to the front. Something else is happening, like perhaps broken HTML partially visible. Are you viewing the browser's page source? You would at least see the opening `<iframe` in the page source.

Comment: Well i suppose i should add that i'm doing this in the command line from my server. I need to use $foo later to run against another database table to delete some rows.

Comment: Does the `$row[0]` value contain a carriage return character (without a newline) by any chance? That would cause the command line to return to the 0 position then overwrite the line.  You could use `trim($row[0])` to guard against that.

Comment: In fact, I think a CR at the end of the db value would produce exactly the weird output you're seeing.

Comment: Here's a sample of some of the db values. I don't think there is.

d8d7904fc0ea8e066b3b  |
85b952b62c14a3a175a6  |
3bcea3b7513ccef5857a  |
6e7b05d79744fbd4c9c1

Comment: Check the output from `strlen($row[0])`. Is it 20 or 21? does `trim()` have an effect?

Comment: @Brett Have you *checked* whether there's an `\r`? Do `bin2hex($row[0])` and look at the last byte(s).

Comment: let me check on the trim, i'm seeing this 0d at the end. Here's the output of 3 db values using bin2hex.

64386437393034666330656138653036366233620d  |
38356239353262363263313461336131373561360d  |
33626365613362373531336363656635383537610d  |

Comment: son of a... that was it trim() solved it. I love you guys, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you are seeing this strange output in the server's command line, it's a clue that something is amiss with the data as it is stored in the database. In particular, be on the lookout for a carriage return character `\r` (hex `0D`) at the end of the `$row[0]` string.

If there's a CR present not followed by a newline `\n`, it will cause the console to return to the start of the current line. It then prints the `%` at the start of the line, overwriting the `<`.

This is solvable by wrapping the database value in `trim()`.

```
$foo ='<iframe src="http://www.website.com/embed/' . trim($row[0]) . '%';
```

You can test for it by inspecting the string with `bin2hex()` and looking for the `0d` at the end, or simply checking that the `strlen()` is the expected length, and not the expected length plus one.

If those carriage returns are not expected there, you should consider fixing the data in your table or at its input source to avoid this problem in the future.

Comment: I guess this would be more of a mysql question, but would it then be safe to assume all values in that specific db table have a CR present?

For instance, lets say that some values don't have a CR present wouldn't i be cutting the last value off of my db value? what can i do about this?

Comment: @BrettK. Maybe, maybe not. If they're all expected to be 20chars, you could `SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(something) > 20` to identify the offenders.  It could be happening at the input source.

Comment: Oh you added to your comment - no, `trim()` won't chop the last character off. It only removes whitespace characters - space, newline, carriage return, tab.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for the help, if i had the rep to upvote i would lol.